# Handling multiple processes

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I have to start about 6 or 7 processes in Iterm2 and would like to start each one in the same single window along with the name of each process given in each sub-window. Moreover, I would like to start these processes from a bash script. Any idea how I might go about this - if it is at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can split a single window into multiple panes using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> and the running process is shown along the top.